# "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" Error

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

```
select 
    ic.item_name,
    lh.locn_brcd from_locn,
    lh2.locn_brcd to_locn,
    wl.from_container,
    wl.to_container,
    wl.units,
    wl.prev_from_container_status prev_from_lpn_status, 
    wl.curr_from_container_status curr_from_lpn_status,
    wl.prev_to_container_status prev_to_lpn_status,
    wl.curr_to_container_status curr_to_lpn_status,
    wl.work_batch_number,
    wl.transaction_name,
    wl.action,
    wl.work_id,
    wl.date_updated,
    wl.source_updated,
    wl.tote_number,
    wl.chute     
from m_work_log wl     
    LEFT join item_cbo ic on wl.item_id=ic.item_id
    left join locn_hdr lh on wl.from_location_id = lh.locn_id
    left join locn_hdr lh2 on wl.to_location_id = lh2.locn_id    
where wl.action in (:action)    
    and trunc(wl.date_updated) between :start_date and :end_date
    and (ic.item_name in (:list) OR  
         wl.source_updated = :username OR 
         wl.to_container in (:LPNList) OR 
         (:list is null and :username is null and :LPNList is null)
        )
    order by date_updated desc
```

Hi everyone,

when I run this code through Oracle SQL Developer and I add two items to the :list parameter and two items to the :action parameter it works fine. But when I run this through SSRS (report builder ) it fails to run and I get an "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator". I'm new to SQL and i'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Multiple Value Parameter:
   First of all, you must use Oracle provider, multiple value paramaters does not work with neither ODBC nor OLEDB connections ([reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31c1ab35-2b78-4d30-9fec-7c95e1cd7d0a/multi-value-parameters-in-ssrs-with-oracle-database?forum=sqlreportingservices)).
   Here is an external link explaining in detail [here](https://arcanecode.com/2008/10/20/sql-server-reporting-services-oracle-and-multivalued-parameters/).
2. Using an expression as the query by putting the whole thing like this `="query_here"`

```
="select "
+ "    ic.item_name,"
+ "    lh.locn_brcd from_locn,"
+ "    lh2.locn_brcd to_locn,"
+ "    wl.from_container,"
+ "    wl.to_container,"
+ "    wl.units,"
+ "    wl.prev_from_container_status prev_from_lpn_status,"
+ "    wl.curr_from_container_status curr_from_lpn_status,"
+ "    wl.prev_to_container_status prev_to_lpn_status,"
+ "    wl.curr_to_container_status curr_to_lpn_status,"
+ "    wl.work_batch_number,"
+ "    wl.transaction_name,"
+ "    wl.action,"
+ "    wl.work_id,"
+ "    wl.date_updated,"
+ "    wl.source_updated,"
+ "    wl.tote_number,"
+ "    wl.chute"
+ "from m_work_log wl"
+ "    LEFT join item_cbo ic on wl.item_id=ic.item_id"
+ "    left join locn_hdr lh on wl.from_location_id = lh.locn_id"
+ "    left join locn_hdr lh2 on wl.to_location_id = lh2.locn_id"
+ "where wl.action in (:action)"
+ "    and trunc(wl.date_updated) between :start_date and :end_date"
+ "    and (ic.item_name in ('" + Join(Parameters!list.Value , "', '")" + ') OR"
+ "         wl.source_updated = :username OR"
+ "         wl.to_container in ('" + Join(Parameters!LPNList.Value , "', '")" + ') OR"
+ "         (:list = '_N/A_' and :username is null and :LPNList = '_N/A_')"
+ "        )"
+ "    order by date_updated desc"
```

In this case you will need to provide default empty values to your lists. I used '*N/A*' in my example.